# Sql query to get data diffrence of total in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables:

1. `booking` - records the order detail

   ```
   id | booking_amount
   -------------------
   1  |            150
   2  |            500
   3  |            400
   ```
2. `payment` - records the payment for order

   ```
   id | booking_id | amount
   ------------------------
   1  |          1 |    100
   2  |          1 |     50
   2  |          2 |    100
   ```

I want to find all bookings where the payments are not complete. With the above data, we expect the answer to be `2,3`, because the sum of payments for `booking_id=1` matches the corresponding `booking_amount` in the `booking_table`.

Comment: I didnt understand what exactly u want. How ur answer is 2,3?

Comment: Please check my question again I have added screenshot

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you have 2 things you need to think about :

1. you want the total amount in your table `payment` by every booking row
2. you want to join your `booking_amount` table with `payment`.

---

Part 1 is quite simple:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as TotalP, booking_id FROM payment GROUP BY booking_id
```

Just a basic query with a simple aggregate function...

---

For part 2, we want to join `booking_amount` and `payment`; the basic `JOIN` would be:

```
SELECT * FROM booking b 
LEFT JOIN payment p ON b.id = p.booking_id
```

We do a `LEFT JOIN` because we may have some booking who are not in the `payment` table. For those bookings, you will get `NULL` value. We will use a `COALESCE` to replace the `NULL` values by `0`.

---

The final query is this:

```
SELECT b.id, COALESCE(TotalP, 0),  b.booking_amount
FROM
 booking b
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT sum(amount) as TotalP, booking_id FROM payment GROUP BY booking_id) as T
ON  b.id = T.booking_id
WHERE COALESCE(TotalP, 0) < b.booking_amount
```

Comment: Very Nice It will help me to write sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a outer join to combine your two tables and look for your conditions. Also, you will need to use SUM(..) function to get the sum of the amount for each id in the payment table.

Please try this:

```
select b.id from booking b 
left outer join -- cant be inner join because we lose id:3 in that case.
(
  select booking_id, SUM(amount) as Total 
  from payment group by booking_id
) p on b.id = p.booking_id
where b.booking_amount > Coalesce(Total,0) --Coalesce is required for such values coming NULL, like id:3, they will be assigned as 0.
```

Comment: When I have tried this Its showing error Invalid use of group function

Comment: I changed. But just notified that it turned on Jean's answer basically. I will look for another way later and update my answer again.

Comment: Yes I don't think there is a better solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.